# NgModule setting provider with Object

Tags: angular, angular5

In my NgModule i could previously set a provider using an object as per the below

```
 providers: [
{ <-- Object 1
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor,
  multi: true
},
{ <-- Object 2
  provide: SignalrWindow, 
  useValue: window 
},
AppSettings,
AuthenticationService,......
```

Now when i try set the providers in this manner i get an error when i use AOT compilation stating:

Invalid provider for the NgModule, - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [[object Object], [object Object] which refers to my two objects....

What is the correct way to specify this object syntax which will allow aot compilation?

Comment: i think this comes from the not-existent `@Injectable` decorators

Comment: @messerbill `@Injectable` affects how DI is performed on provider instantiation, not provider registration.

Comment: @estus thus i have no idea why this is not working >.<

Comment: This is surely a problem, `useValue: window`. There's no `window` global during AOT compilation. Use `useFactory`